# How do I modify an inherited attribute that is not held in a variable?

Tags: python

I want to inherit everything from the `UserScoreboard` class and only change the position of the `ComputerScoreboard` to be (-40, 230) instead of (40, 230). How do I implement that?

```
from turtle import Turtle

class UserScoreboard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.goto(40, 230)
        self.write(f"{self.score}", font=("courier", 50, "normal"))

    def update_score(self):
        self.score += 1


class ComputerScoreboard(UserScoreboard):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.goto(-40, 230)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement it in a function which can be overriden:

```py
class UserScoreboard(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.go_to_position()
        self.write(f"{self.score}", font=("courier", 50, "normal"))
    
    def update_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        
    def go_to_position(self):
        self.goto(40, 230)
    
    
class ComputerScoreboard(UserScoreboard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def go_to_position(self):
        self.goto(-40, 230)
```

Standalone, runnable example:

```
class UserScoreboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.go_to_position()

    def go_to_position(self):
        print('self.goto(40, 230)')


class ComputerScoreboard(UserScoreboard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def go_to_position(self):
        print('self.goto(-40, 230)')

UserScoreboard()
ComputerScoreboard()
```

outputs

```
self.goto(40, 230)
self.goto(-40, 230)
```